# Timeout in mutli-threaded script

Tags: python, multithreading

Unlike this: [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call)

I'm trying to timeout a line of code within a thread (not the main thread).

Signal only works in main thread, so I can't use that.

The line I want to limit is a web request with the requests library:

```
s.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

I can't use requests built-in timeout, because it doesn't always time out under certain conditions.

Comment: do you have access to the thread where you do s.get("https://www.google.com/") ?

Comment: @ranjith not sure what you mean, but yeah it's all in 1 script that i wrote myself

Comment: i meant are you using say pythons threading library or something similar ? As in th = threading.Thread(target = your_function, name="thread_name"); th.start() ?

Comment: @ranjith yup that is exactly what i am running

Comment: @ranjith and within that thread, there is like 50 lines of code and a few nested loops. i just need to wrap the web requests somehow.

Comment: ok, got some solutions will post in answer

Comment: @User can you specify why you can't use requests built-in timeout?

Comment: @A.Albershteyn because it only times out in some cases

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python's standard threading library, I don't think there is an easy way to terminate the thread once it has started. There are some options mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread) (:D), you could perhaps try.
If you don't care when the thread completes and just want control back, you can provide timeout in join method. It would look like below,

```
th = threading.Thread(target=f)
th.start()    #starts thread
th.join(timeout=10) # you get control back in 10 seconds, but thread could still be running
if th.is_alive():
    print("still alive")
```

Other option (which I like) would be to use [concurrent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) library,

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    future = executor.submit(pow, 323, 1235)
    print(future.result(timeout=10))    #within 10 seconds if result isn't returned you will get TimeoutError
```

Quoting from docs on result(timeout=None),

> If the call hasn’t completed in timeout seconds, then a
>   concurrent.futures.TimeoutError will be raised. timeout can be an int
>   or float. If timeout is not specified or None, there is no limit to
>   the wait time

Comment: So you suggest putting the request into another thread? So a thread created within a thread?

Comment: if you have code that aren't blocked on the results, why not

Comment: well the code after of course relies on the response of the request

Comment: ok, you could still create new thread for http call and if you don't get results in time, proceed with your other part of the code